# Nginx: stat() failed (13: permission denied)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am using the default config while adding the specific directory with nginx installed on my ubuntu 12.04 machine.

```
server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                root /username/test/static;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
...

...
}
```

I just want a simple static nginx server to serve files out of that directory. However, checking the `error.log` I see

```
2014/09/10 16:55:16 [crit] 10808#0: *2 stat() "/username/test/static/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client:, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "domain"
2014/09/10 16:55:16 [error] 10808#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html
```

I've already done `chown -R www-data:www-data` on `/username/test/static`, I've set them to `chmod 755`. I don't know what else needs to be set.

Comment: Check if the `www-data` user can `cd` to the `/username/test/static` directory: `sudo -u www-data cd /username/test/static`

Comment: I am getting permission denied , but when i do ls -l it shows that its set to www-data user

Comment: Could it be that /username is on encryptfs? I am having exactly the same issues with /home/username folder, where my site is located. If I move it out of encryptfs then all works fine.
Still no solution for me...

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Nginx operates within the directory, so if you can't `cd` to that directory from the nginx user then it will fail (as does the `stat` command in your log). Make sure the `www-user` can `cd` all the way to the `/username/test/static`. You can confirm that the `stat` will fail or succeed by running

```
sudo -u www-data stat /username/test/static
```

In your case probably the `/username` directory is the issue here. Usually `www-data` does not have permissions to `cd` to other users home directories.

The best solution in that case would be to add `www-data` to `username` group:

```
gpasswd -a www-data username
```

and make sure that `username` group can enter all directories along the path:

```
chmod g+x /username && chmod g+x /username/test && chmod g+x /username/test/static
```

For your changes to work, restart nginx

```
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Does it mean for every new directory added under the root, chmod has to be done to the new directories?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen keep in mind that this is OS level permission system, so in POSIX systems it depends on your [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). If you need a more generic solution, that doesn't require `chmod`ing every new directory, then there is a solution. It requires reverse group association (`username` to `www-data` group) and the use of `setgid`. Feel free to post a new question for more elaborate description and I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: What if my path is in /root/ directory? Is it safe to do chmod g+x on /root ?
And adding www-data to root group ?

Comment: On Fedora 24 my issue came about with... ACL permissions... another layer... YEY!

Comment: Well my `nginx` user can able to access my website directory but still it says permission denied on the error logs.

Comment: omg thank you thank you.! `gpasswd -a www-data username` was the answer.

Comment: Why to username group? in my case username group does not exist. Then which should I use?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried almost one night. `sudo -u nginx stat /root/app/html` helped me, and I found the parent folder `/root/` does not have execute permission on others.

Comment: Though, gpasswd -a www-data username worked for me.  

But deleting the files & directories & taking a fresh copy of it worked as well.

Comment: you're a god amongst men

Comment: Security-wise, is adding `www-data` to the `username` group considered to be safe?

Comment: I've literally spent 6 hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my nginx configuration.. omg thanks a lot!

Answer (score 224):

Nginx need to have +x access on all directories leading to the site's root directory.

Ensure you have +x on all of the directories in the path leading to the site's root. For example, if the site root is /home/username/siteroot:

```
chmod +x /home/
chmod +x /home/username
chmod +x /home/username/siteroot
```

Comment: thank you Krish!! It works and with a clean explanation

Comment: I have already double checked everything but no success! This was what I missed.

Comment: This is the right answer, because this answer explains the root of the problem! Needed (+x access) but not (+r access) as expected by default.

Comment: Thank you. After everything I tried. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Not sure how I've never ran into this before. This is what I needed after fighting permission denied errors for a few hours. Thank you!

Comment: Saw something else that was suggesting this, but didn't specifically mention that it needs to be every directory leading to the site's root. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 121):

I've just had the same problem on a CentOS 7 box.

Seems I'd hit selinux. Putting selinux into permissive mode (`setenforce permissive`) has worked round the problem for now. I'll try and get back with a proper fix.

Comment: This is the exact "not documented" behavior I was trying to understand for these last 3 days...

Comment: Here is a post about this behavior: http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/

Comment: So, I found myself back here...
This time I find I copied the file in question from my home directory to the html directory, and updated the ownership. Same issue as 2015...
Better fix:

`ls -Z myFile.js` will show the SELinux context:
`-rw-r--r--. nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 myFile.js`

Use `chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t myFile` to change the SELinux content.

Comment: Yup; I had the same issue. `sudo setenforce 0` fixed it for me.

Comment: Tried every single solution online for days.. this worked in a second #facepalm

Comment: NGINX has some pretty great docs about this here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/#Issue-2:-File-Access-is-Forbidden

Comment: Just a note, if you want selinux completely disabled, you'll need to change the `SELINUX` value to `disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config`, followed by a reboot. When it's set to `permissive`, it can still run checks behind the scenes (using valuable CPU), but take no action.

Comment: I've never had any benefit from SElinux, and I've frequently had problems like this with it. :/

Comment: the easy 'proper fix' is to only serve files from inside /usr/share/nginx/ which is permitted by default. if you absolutely need to serve files stored in another directory  have a look at 'Issue 2: File Access is Forbidden' here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/

Comment: Thanks Andrew Richard Miller,
It's very helpful.

Answer (score 39):

On CentOS 7.0 I had this `Access Deined` problem caused by SELinux and these steps resolved the issue:

```
yum install -y policycoreutils-devel
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
semodule -i nginx.pp
```

**Update:** Just a side-note from what I've learned while using digitalocean's virtual Linux servers, or as they call them *Droplets*. Using SELinux requires a decent amount of RAM. It's most probably like you won't be able to run and **manage** SELinux on a droplet with less than 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  It did solve my problem (also on CentOS 7) to begin with, but then I was blocked by a second denial elsewhere, so resorted to `setenforce 0`.  However, when looking back at what this solution actually does, I realised that I needed to re-run the commands to update the permissions for the nginx user.  That seemed to work and I could set SELinux back to enforcing.

Comment: Well, this may be a bit too late. Still, it's worth mentioning that when you keep SELinux enforcing; it is imperative to remember, software like Nginx insert their own set of rules like default ports, default paths, read/write access to paths, etc. into SELinux. If you don't want any trouble, you must follow those rules (like putting your HTML/PHP files into /var/www) or else prepare to overcome problems originating deep in the SELinux context.
This can be helpful [CentOS < 8]:
https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/nginx-selinux-configuration

Answer (score 38):

You may have Security-Enhanced Linux running, so add rule for that.
I had permission 13 errors, even though permissions were set and user existed..

`chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /username/test/static`

Comment: Thanks! Worked on CentOS release 6.10 (Final).

Comment: Worked on CentOS 7.5.1804 (Core).

Answer (score 34):

To check the default Nginx users:

```
sudo ps aux| grep nginx
```

You will get an output like this:

```
root       69558  0.0  0.0  66276  1708 ?        Ss   10:14   0:00 
nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   69559  0.0  0.1  66516  5540 ?        S    10:14   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   69560  0.0  0.1  66516  6944 ?        S    10:14   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       69794  0.0  0.0   8168   672 pts/1    S+   10:19   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Also, check the nginx.conf file using any text editor of your choice: I will be using vim:

```
vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

[image]

Solution:

1. Change the www-data user in the nginx.conf file to root, in case you are on root user.
   [image]

2. The Second solution is to add the user www-data to root group.

Comment: after over 10hrs of searching, this was what worked for me, thanks

Comment: Is it a safe action? Can I use it in the production envitonment?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things, but for security reasons I would use the second approach instead. Making nginx root is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
After digging deep.
your answer helped me.

Comment: Finally, after days of struggling with this, fixing file & folder permissions, incl. SELinux ones, this is the only thing that worked on my docker+nginx mounted volume setup.

Comment: Allowing web server to be in root group or running as root user invites unwanted security exposures and should be avoided at all cost. Use most upvoted answer.

Comment: See answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859782/4400875) and discussion here (https://serverfault.com/a/1010924) about root on nginx, not worth it and the other answer is very simple to do anyways.

Answer (score 15):

**This is how i fixed this**

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/ec2-user
```

Comment: This worked for me. But more explaination of the issue would have been best.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I kept getting "chmod: changing permissions of '/home/': Operation not permitted" when trying the answers from above. Big thanks.

Comment: my nginx user could not change directory to required destination.

above command worked for me.

Comment: This worked and intuitively we could say the accepted answer of setting the proxy server as root would be a big risk and here is a discussion on that - https://serverfault.com/a/1010924

Comment: Spent a whole day trying to fix this and no AI helped me lol. This worked. Thanks! Replace `ec2-user` with your appropriate username.

Comment: I want to upvote 1M times!! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I finally found my way through. In short, let's say your username is `joe` and you hold a website under your personal filesystem `/home/joe/path/to/website`.

You literally have to tell the system that `nginx` is your pal.
Place `nginx` in `joe` group :

```sh
sudo gpasswd -a nginx joe
```

After that if it still doesn't work, check right access of `/home/joe` directory.  That's probably the reason why nginx can't reach the file because even if he is your friend now you have to open him the door to your house :

```sh
sudo chmod g+x /home/joe
```

That's it. That's literally all you have to do to give nginx access to your local files :)

I don't think there are security concerns with this method because `nginx` is the high authority and only an admin can change the group. `nginx` can now read what's in `joe` directories. It's only a security breach if the holder of the `nginx` account is different with the user you open directory access from, but in my case I'm the holder of both parties, that is in a local context.

Comment: Changing home folder to executable (chmod g+x) works in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Symptom:

Could not upload images to WordPress Media Library.

Cause:

(CentOS) `yum update`

Error:

```
2014/10/22 18:08:50 [crit] 23286#0: *5332 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000003" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 1.2.3.4, server: _, request: "POST /wp-admin/media-new.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example/wp-admin/media-new.php"
```

Solution:

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx`

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem, I solved it to give permissions to nginx user and group something like this:

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /username/test/static
```

Comment: actually worked, notice that if you are running nginx in docker container and your nginx.conf file starts with user nginx; so in your dockerfile you should have    copy ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf    RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/  to give your user the write privilege

Answer (score 3):

Change your `nginx.conf` `user` property to `www-static` files owener.

```
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user your_user_name;

# same other config
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the static data, when you install the nginx, will be in /var/www/html. 
So you can just copy your static folder into /var/html/ and set the

```
root /var/www/<your static folder>
```

in ngix.conf (or /etc/nginx/sites-available/default)

This worked for me on ubuntu but I guess it should not be much different for other distros.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the folder which served the files was a symbolic link to another folder, made with

```
ln -sf /origin /var/www/destination
```

Even though the permissions (user and group) where correct on the destination folder (the symbolic link), I still had the error because Nginx needed to have permissions to the origin folder whole's hierarchy as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I am using Plesk Onyx 17 with Centos7. I could see this error in proxy_error_log under the affected domain's logs. All the dirs/files in /var/www/vhosts/ are owned by respective users (domain owners) and you can see that all of them are in psacln group. So solution was to add nginx also to this group, so he can see what he needs:

```
usermod -aG psacln nginx
```

And indeed, restart nginx and reload page with Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the privilege problem... For me, its because i use the /root/** as the nginx root, it need higher privilege. An easy way is just move the project into a directory created by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I found a work around:
Moved the folder to nginx configuration folder, in my case "/etc/nginx/my-web-app".
And then changed the permissions to root user "sudo chown -R root:root "my-web-app".

Answer (score -2):

1. sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
2. change user
   from:
   user www-data;
   to:
   user root;
3. restart nginx

Comment: Do not start Nginx as root or regular user, this is a critical security flaw !!!

Answer (score -5):

You can also add which user will run the nginx. In the nginx.conf file, make the following changes:

```
user root;
```

You can add the above line as the first line in your nginx conf.
You can write the name of any user who has the permission to write in that directory.