# nginx: "/root/index.html" forbidden (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx, server, fedora

I am installing nginx. Here is the steps I followed:

- Make index.html file in /root directory
- edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. After edit it looks like this:

  ```
  user  nginx;
  worker_processes  1;

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  ...

  http {
     ...

     server {
          listen       80 default_server;
          server_name  my_domain_name.com;
          root   /root;
      ...
  }
  ```
- following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774999/nginx-stat-failed-13-permission-denied) question I gave away permissions:

> gpasswd -a nginx root
>
> chmod g+x /root

(sorry, couldn't correctly format as code)

- I restarted server:

> service nginx restart

I visited my_domain_name.com and got 403 error. /var/log/nginx/error.log content:

```
"/root/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 117.211.86.108, server: my_domain_name.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my_domain_name.com"
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Oh! Please [don't disable SELinux](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/).

### Don't use `/root` — it's a trap!

First — do you *really* need to serve files from `/root`? That's actually the home directory for the root *user account*, not meant to be the *web* root.

Instead, use `/var/www/html` or (my preference) `/srv/www`.

If you *do* use `/root`, make sure you're not exposing ssh keys or `authorized_keys` files, database passwords, or anything similar. Using `/root` to serve web pages is really just a bad idea all around.
(But... no shame here: it's clearly confusing, and kind of a trap set by history due to the name 'root' being used for multiple concepts.)

### Make SELinux work for you!

Second, rather than disabling SELinux (which, in this case, is protecting you from doing something dangerous), you should configure it properly. In Fedora Linux, the SELinux policy as designed so nginx shares this with other webservers, so, using `/srv/www/yoursite` as the root,

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /srv/www/yoursite
```

should do it.

(This answer should also apply to all of the "Enterprise Linux" distributions that are downstream from Fedora Linux — that is, RHEL, CentOS Linux, CentOS Stream, Alma Linux, Rocky Linux, etc., etc.)

Comment: I wasted hours on this thing...just thank you!

Comment: This solutions applies to a Centos sever too.

Comment: 3 hours wasted before I landed here. THANK YOU!
- Working on CentOS

Comment: Many thanks from RHEL land!

Comment: Great answer. Using `/root` was the problem in my case too. Once I updated the index.html path to elsewhere (other than `/root`), nginx home page came up. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

I was on an amazon linux instance, had to do

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/ec2-user/
sudo service nginx restart
```

Not sure what the security implications are.

For Nginx, Giving (+) Users (o) Executable (x) permissions needs to go all the way down to the folder you want to serve (example=folder with index.html file). So for example if you're using Angular, set the `/dist` folder to `o+x` permissions otherwise Nginx might throw a 403 Forbidden error.

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/username/web_project/dist
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score -3):

I solved it by disable SELINUX and reboot

vi /etc/selinux/config

```
#SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUX=disabled
```

reboot

Comment: This isn't really _solving_ it. This approach forgoes the very real protection against compromise that SELinux can provide — in this case, it's usually _very bad_ if ngnix is serving files from `/root` — despite the name, that directory is _not_ meant to be a web root. Please see my answer.