# Nginx try_files doesnt search files

Tags: nginx

After reinstalling ubuntu nginx config doesn't want to work. `try_files` with correct `root` path doesn't find files.
Here is my config

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name maiden.local evermaiden.local;

       root /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public;
       access_log /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public/logs/nginx.log mrgl;

       location / {
                   try_files $uri $uri/ @clj;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }

       location @clj {
                   proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4444;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
}
```

Log format:

```
log_format mrgl '\n uri: $uri'
                '\n document root: $document_root'
                '\n realpath root: $realpath_root'
                '\n doc + uri: $document_root$uri';
```

Log output:

```
uri: /test.jpg
document root: /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public
realpath root: -
doc + uri: /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public/test.jpg

uri: /assets/common.css
document root: /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public
realpath root: -
doc + uri: /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public/assets/common.css

uri: /assets/evermaiden.js
document root: /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public
realpath root: -
doc + uri: /home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public/assets/evermaiden.js
```

What is going wrong here? Nginx have access to the folder(log file work well), all that files exist and store near logs/nginx.log...  first request should return image, but it proceed to the server-_- another requests should return assets, but...
I tried to reinstall it with `purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full`, I tried other versions (1.12->1.13) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: what does the error log says?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@TarunLalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) i remembered about default logs in /var/logs and when i visit it.... it was *facepalm* -_-

```
 2017/09/20 23:13:44 [crit] 30316#30316: *1 realpath() "/home/aeonax/lid/evermaiden/resources/public" 
 failed (13: Permission denied) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: maiden.local, 
 request: "GET /test.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:4444/test.jpg", host: "maiden.local"
```

After this, problem disappeared and i found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774999/nginx-stat-failed-13-permission-denied).

---

```
make sure that username group can enter all directories along the path:

chmod g+x /username && chmod g+x /username/test && chmod g+x /username/test/static
```