# nginx permission issue serving static file on centos 7

Tags: nginx, centos7

- I have Nginx installed with PHP-FPM ( php 7.2) on a CentOS 7
- I created a new account with name deploy
- I added deploy to group deploy, added deploy to group Nginx
- I created a folder in deploy's home web/public, then set permission `777 -R web/public/`
- then I changed `user = deploy`, `group = deploy` in  `/etc/opt/remi/php72/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
- SELinux disabled

My problem is:
- I can run php, but cannot access static file ( css, js... ) via browser

This is an error message:

> - 19/04/27 22:51:22 [error] 4165#0: *1601 open() "/home/deploy/web/public/robots.txt" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 216.244.66.xxx, server: _, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"

This is Nginx setting

```
server {
listen  80;
server_name  domain.con;
root   /home/deploy/web/public;

index  index.html index.php;

error_log /var/logs/nginx/error_log error;
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
             root   /home/deploy/web/public;
            autoindex on;
            access_log on;
            expires max;
            log_not_found on;
    }
```

Please help me

Update, solution is:

```
chmod +x /home/deploy
chmod +x /home/deploy/public
```

Comment: You're changing the permission for the wrong folder `www/`? Change this folder `/home/deploy/web/public`

Comment: Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774999/nginx-stat-failed-13-permission-denied) I believe it will help.

Comment: @KhalidAli  run `chmod +x /home/username` it worked for me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Run commands:

```
chmod +x /home/deploy
chmod +x /home/deploy/public
```