# Why does child process get 13(Permission denied) when open the file created by parent process in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, filesystems, fork, permission-denied

I am trying to write a plugin in `nginx`, I should create a file in `main process` then `child process` will read this file. I have set the file `0766` in `main process`, but `open` and `statvfs` failed when I try to open the file in `child process`, the `errno` is 13 which means `Permission denied`.

Is there any special settings between `parent` and `child` processes? How can I solve it?

my code is like this:

```
// in nginx main process I create the file
u_char* shared_addr = NULL; 
int map_my_file(const char* path)
{
    extern int errno;
    umask(0);
    int fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0766);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        ngx_log_stderr(0, "open file failed %s, %d", path, errno);
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd, 1024 *1024) < 0)
    {
        printf("ftruncate %d failed", fd);
    }
    shared_addr = (u_char*)mmap(NULL, 1024 * 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
}

// in nginx child process, I try to open the file 
    int cfd = 0;
    if ((cfd = open("./t.log", O_RDWR)) >= 0)
    {
        printf("child open success\n");
    } else {
        printf("failed %d\n", errno);
    }
// I got `failed 13`, means `Permission denied`
```

If I take these `create` and `open` codes out separately and put them in a sample `parent-child` process case, it can works correctly. But it can not work in `nginx`, always told me `13`.

Comment: Try disabling SELinux first and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Originally there is not SELinux installed on my server, After I installed it , disable it and restart server, it is still the same error.

Comment: Well, `extern int errno;` [is absolutely wrong](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p2): "If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, **or a program defines an identifier with the name errno, the behavior is undefined**."  First, get rid of that and [use the proper `#include <errno.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I delete `extern int errno`, still get the same error number 13, and if I use `statvfs` to get the fold information, still get 13, but if I try `statvfs` in a separate sample case, it can work fine. I wonder if there some special settings in `nginx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons lead to this error

1. I did not set `user` in `nginx.conf`, thus nobody will control the
   work process in default according [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user), `Nginx` will set user
   when child process [initializes](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/1a8ef991d92d22eb8aded7f49595dd31a639e8a4/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L753).
2. The `child process` needs `x` access on all directories, see
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686446/21771470).

Check the following:

```
chmod +x /home/
chmod +x /home/username
chmod +x /home/username/siteroot
```